# проверить делимость одного числа на другое без использования условий

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как проверить делимость одного числа на другое без использования условий?

Answer (score 7):

```
In [57]: def chk(a,b):
    ...:     return a % b and 'не делится' or 'делится'
    ...:

In [58]: chk(15, 5)
Out[58]: 'делится'

In [59]: chk(15, 4)
Out[59]: 'не делится'
```

Comment: Красиво, конечно, но нечитаемо, и как это можно использовать без `if`??

Comment: @andy.37, я видел подобные присваивания в библиотеках Python: `variable = parameter or default_value`

Comment: Это, все же, скорее perl-идиоматика. Я бы написал `var = parameter if parameter else default_value`. А уж если больше одного логического оператора... write-only код получается. Впрочем, ответ абсолютно верен, + поставил.

Comment: @andy.37, я бы тоже так в реальном коде написал ;) Просто это первое, что пришло на ум, чтобы без использования `if ...`

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Да это везде работает, я не знаю языков с "неленивыми" AND и OR. Просто `do_something() or die` - классическая perl-идиома, в других языках это скорее экзотика, да и нечитабельно это.

Comment: Ещё одна менее желаемая альтернатива `'делится' if a % b == 0 else 'не делится'` будет: `['не делится', 'делится'][a % b == 0]`

Comment: это совершенно необходимо сжать до 1 линии `chk = lambda a, b: a % b and 'не делится' or 'делится'`

Comment: @AndrioSkur, можно, но совершенно не необходимо... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Немного извращения. Функция вернет ноль, если числа не делятся целиком, и результат если делятся:

```
def f(a, b):
    return ((a%b+2)/(a%b+1)/2) * (a/b)

f(16,2) #8
f(16,3) #0
```

Comment: А если a=0? Но тоже красиво.